# How can I remove a no longer existent child domain from my forest?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

In a virtual environment, I lost the virtualized DCs of a child domain of my forest. I don't need the child domain, but as the DCs are gone now, I cannot remove the domain in the intended way by demoting the child DCs. How can I finally get rid of the child domain in my forest and delete all traces of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove an orphaned child domain the hard way by performing the following steps:

1. Determine the domain controller that holds the *Domain Naming Master* Flexible Single Master Operations (FSMO) role of your forest:

   ```
   netdom query fsmo
   ```

   Logon to it as an enterprise administrator to perform the next steps.
2. Remove the child domain controllers from your forest ([source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/925ff421-b32e-426d-b55a-ec6f73c28e6a/how-to-completely-remove-an-orphaned-child-domain-without-its-dc)):

   > 1. At the command prompt, type `ntdsutil`, and then press Enter.
   > 2. Type `metadata cleanup`, and then press Enter.
   > 3. Type `connections`, and then press Enter.
   > 4. Type `connect to server <servername>`, where  is the name of the domain controller that holds the Domain Naming Master FSMO Role. Then press Enter. You should receive confirmation that the connection is successfully established.
   > 5. Type `quit`, and then press Enter. The **Metadata Cleanup** menu is displayed.
   > 6. Type `select operation target`, and then press Enter.
   > 7. Type `list sites`, and then press Enter. A list of sites in the forest is displayed, each with an associated number.
   > 8. Type `select site <number>`, and then press Enter, where **number** is the number associated with the site that contains the domain to be removed.
   > 9. Type `list domains in site`, and then press Enter. A list of domains in the site is displayed, each with an associated number.
   > 10. Type `select domain <number>`, and then press Enter, where **number** is the number associated with the domain to be removed.
   > 11. Type `list servers for domain in site`, and then press Enter. A list of domain controllers in the domain is displayed, each with an associated number.
   > 12. Type `select server <number>`, and then press Enter, where **number** is the number associated with the domain controller to be removed.
   > 13. Type `quit`, and then press Enter. The **Metadata Cleanup** menu is displayed.
   > 14. Type `remove selected server`, and then press Enter. You should receive confirmation that the removal was successful.
   > 15. Now jump directly to step 3.10. or type `quit` at each menu to quit the NTDSUTIL tool. You should receive confirmation that the connection disconnected successfully.

   Repeat these steps for all remaining domain controllers of your child domain to be removed.
3. Remove the child domain from your forest ([source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/remove-orphaned-domains)):

   > 1. At the command prompt, type `ntdsutil`, and then press Enter.
   > 2. Type `metadata cleanup`, and then press Enter.
   > 3. Type `connections`, and then press Enter.
   > 4. Type `connect to server <servername>`, where  is the name of the domain controller that holds the Domain Naming Master FSMO Role. Then press Enter. You should receive confirmation that the connection is successfully established.
   > 5. Type `quit`, and then press Enter. The **Metadata Cleanup** menu is displayed.
   > 6. Type `select operation target`, and then press Enter.
   > 7. Type `list domains`, and then press Enter. A list of domains in the forest is displayed, each with an associated number.
   > 8. Type `select domain <number>`, and then press Enter, where **number** is the number associated with the domain to be removed.
   > 9. Type `quit`, and then press Enter. The **Metadata Cleanup** menu is displayed.
   > 10. Type `remove selected domain`, and then press Enter. You should receive confirmation that the removal was successful. If an error occurs, see the Microsoft Knowledge Base for articles on specific error messages.
   > 11. Type `quit` at each menu to quit the NTDSUTIL tool. You should receive confirmation that the connection disconnected successfully.
4. Open the *Active Directory Sites and Services* console (`dssite.msc`) and remove the domain controllers of the domain to be removed from their site, manually.
5. Open the *Active Directory Domains and Trusts* console (`domain.msc`) and remove all trust relationships to the domain to be deleted from all other domains.
6. Remove all entries in DNS related to the domain to be removed, also the SRV records.